# Extract argument fields from a script using bash commands awk sed etc

Tags: python, bash, awk, sed

I'm trying to extract all arguments from various scripts that are used in function arguments.
I have the function names used to lookup the arguments and I'm currently hacking it apart using awk and FS to extract the known field. But it's not good enough. I have some lines where two functions are present checking an OR condition for each.
The syntax is also different based on the coder:

- FUNCT('ARGUMENT')
- FUNCT("ARGUMENT")
- FUNCT ('ARGUMENT')
- FUNCT('ARGUMENT') ||  FUNCT('ARGUMENT2')
- FUNCT('ARGUMENT') && FUNCT('ARGUMENT2')

My current script splits the line around the FUNCT call, then splits any end comments denoted by ";" and then strips all the characters away from the argument. But it can't handle the last case, so I have to create a separate script.

> awk 'NF>0 $1 ~ !/^*/ {SPLIT($0,a,"FUNCT"); split(a[2],b,";"); if (length(b[1]>0){ print FILENAME","b[1] }}' * | sed 's/FUNCT//g' | sed 's/[()'''" ]//g'

My ultimate goal is to extract the list of those arguments to a file then match them with a database of arguments. The other approach is to loop through the database of arguments and find which scripts they are in with a simple grep check but the database requires a bunch of formatting to get it to a simple text list to ingest also.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using awk and sed to strip out the pieces you don't want, you could instead use Perl to pull out just the pieces you DO want:

```
# cat test.txt
FUNCT('ARGUMENT')
FUNCT("ARGUMENT")
FUNCT ('ARGUMENT')
FUNCT('ARGUMENT') || FUNCT('ARGUMENT2')
FUNCT('ARGUMENT') && FUNCT('ARGUMENT2')
NOFUNCT("ARGUMENT")

# perl -ne '
my $q = q{["'\'']};
my @args = /\bFUNCT\s*\($q(\w+)$q\)/g;
print "@args\n" if @args;
' test.txt
ARGUMENT
ARGUMENT
ARGUMENT
ARGUMENT ARGUMENT2
ARGUMENT ARGUMENT2
```